# Internal laptop camera disconnecting and connecting every 30 seconds

Tags: webcam, camera

I really need help on this cause I'm getting crazy, and honestly very disappointed with the stability of ubuntu, because I can't have a normal video-conference with anyone and as you can imagine that is a must nowadays. I searched already a lot in google and here and found no stable solution yet.

Since some months ago, the web internal camera of the laptop simply disconnects after 25-30 seconds and then reconnects again. In some video software the camera reconnects and I have to bear with a blink every 30 seconds and in other platforms such as in zoom the video simply freezes.

### Features

- A Toshiba Satellite laptop
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

### Some CLI outputs

```
$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD: TOSHIB (usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.3):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video2
```

```
$ v4l2-ctl --device=/dev/video0 --all
Driver Info (not using libv4l2):
    Driver name   : uvcvideo
    Card type     : TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD: TOSHIB
    Bus info      : usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.3
    Driver version: 5.4.151
    Capabilities  : 0x84A00001
        Video Capture
        Metadata Capture
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
        Device Capabilities
    Device Caps   : 0x04200001
        Video Capture
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
Priority: 2
Video input : 0 (Camera 1: ok)
Format Video Capture:
    Width/Height      : 1280/720
    Pixel Format      : 'MJPG'
    Field             : None
    Bytes per Line    : 0
    Size Image        : 1843200
    Colorspace        : sRGB
    Transfer Function : Default (maps to sRGB)
    YCbCr/HSV Encoding: Default (maps to ITU-R 601)
    Quantization      : Default (maps to Full Range)
    Flags             : 
Crop Capability Video Capture:
    Bounds      : Left 0, Top 0, Width 1280, Height 720
    Default     : Left 0, Top 0, Width 1280, Height 720
    Pixel Aspect: 1/1
Selection: crop_default, Left 0, Top 0, Width 1280, Height 720
Selection: crop_bounds, Left 0, Top 0, Width 1280, Height 720
Streaming Parameters Video Capture:
    Capabilities     : timeperframe
    Frames per second: 30.000 (30/1)
    Read buffers     : 0
                     brightness 0x00980900 (int)    : min=0 max=100 step=1 default=50 value=50
                       contrast 0x00980901 (int)    : min=0 max=100 step=1 default=32 value=32
                     saturation 0x00980902 (int)    : min=0 max=100 step=1 default=32 value=32
                            hue 0x00980903 (int)    : min=-4 max=4 step=1 default=0 value=0
 white_balance_temperature_auto 0x0098090c (bool)   : default=1 value=1
                          gamma 0x00980910 (int)    : min=1 max=16 step=1 default=8 value=8
           power_line_frequency 0x00980918 (menu)   : min=0 max=2 default=1 value=1
      white_balance_temperature 0x0098091a (int)    : min=2800 max=6500 step=1 default=5000 value=5000 flags=inactive
                      sharpness 0x0098091b (int)    : min=0 max=20 step=1 default=4 value=4
         backlight_compensation 0x0098091c (int)    : min=0 max=1 step=1 default=0 value=0
                  exposure_auto 0x009a0901 (menu)   : min=0 max=3 default=3 value=3
         exposure_auto_priority 0x009a0903 (bool)   : default=0 value=1
```

```
$ v4l2-ctl --device=/dev/video2 --all
Driver Info (not using libv4l2):
    Driver name   : uvcvideo
    Card type     : TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD: TOSHIB
    Bus info      : usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.3
    Driver version: 5.4.151
    Capabilities  : 0x84A00001
        Video Capture
        Metadata Capture
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
        Device Capabilities
    Device Caps   : 0x04A00000
        Metadata Capture
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
Priority: 2
```

```
$ sudo journalctl  --follow | tee jc.log
-- Logs begin at Wed 2021-10-06 08:33:44 CEST. --
Dec 25 14:49:10 toshiba /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/input/input37/event6"
Dec 25 14:49:10 toshiba /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD: TOSHIB" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
Dec 25 14:49:10 toshiba /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
Dec 25 14:49:10 toshiba /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "pt"
Dec 25 14:49:10 toshiba /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
Dec 25 14:49:10 toshiba /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (WW) Option "xkb_options" requires a string value
Dec 25 14:49:10 toshiba /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (II) event6  - TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD: TOSHIB: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Dec 25 14:49:10 toshiba /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (II) event6  - TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD: TOSHIB: device is a keyboard
Dec 25 14:49:21 toshiba sudo[16526]:     joao : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/joao ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl --follow
Dec 25 14:49:21 toshiba sudo[16526]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec 25 14:50:18 toshiba kernel: usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 15
Dec 25 14:50:18 toshiba kernel: uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
Dec 25 14:50:18 toshiba cheese[6182]: cheese_preferences_dialog_on_source_change: assertion '_tmp2_ > ((guint) 0)' failed
Dec 25 14:50:18 toshiba kernel: uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
Dec 25 14:50:18 toshiba cheese[6182]: cheese_camera_device_get_name: assertion 'CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed
Dec 25 14:50:18 toshiba cheese[6182]: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
Dec 25 14:50:18 toshiba cheese[6182]: g_variant_ref_sink: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
Dec 25 14:50:18 toshiba cheese[6182]: g_settings_schema_key_type_check: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
Dec 25 14:50:18 toshiba cheese[6182]: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
Dec 25 14:50:18 toshiba cheese[6182]: g_settings_set_value: key 'camera' in 'org.gnome.Cheese' expects type 's', but a GVariant of type '(null)' was given
Dec 25 14:50:18 toshiba cheese[6182]: g_variant_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
Dec 25 14:50:18 toshiba cheese[6182]: cheese_preferences_dialog_setup_resolutions_for_device: assertion 'device != NULL' failed
Dec 25 14:50:18 toshiba kernel: uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
Dec 25 14:50:18 toshiba kernel: uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
Dec 25 14:50:18 toshiba kernel: uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
Dec 25 14:50:18 toshiba /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (II) config/udev: removing device TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD: TOSHIB
Dec 25 14:50:18 toshiba /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (**) Option "fd" "59"
Dec 25 14:50:18 toshiba /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (II) event6  - TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD: TOSHIB: device removed
Dec 25 14:50:18 toshiba /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Dec 25 14:50:18 toshiba /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:70
Dec 25 14:50:18 toshiba upowerd[1299]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.1
Dec 25 14:50:18 toshiba upowerd[1299]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0
Dec 25 14:50:18 toshiba upowerd[1299]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3
Dec 25 14:50:18 toshiba gnome-shell[1790]: g_array_unref: assertion 'array' failed
Dec 25 14:50:19 toshiba kernel: usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 16 using ehci-pci
Dec 25 14:50:19 toshiba kernel: usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b448, bcdDevice=49.02
Dec 25 14:50:19 toshiba kernel: usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Dec 25 14:50:19 toshiba kernel: usb 1-1.3: Product: TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD
Dec 25 14:50:19 toshiba kernel: usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Namuga
Dec 25 14:50:20 toshiba kernel: uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD (04f2:b448)
Dec 25 14:50:20 toshiba kernel: input: TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD: TOSHIB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/input/input38
Dec 25 14:50:20 toshiba mtp-probe[18900]: checking bus 1, device 16: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3"
Dec 25 14:50:20 toshiba mtp-probe[18900]: bus: 1, device: 16 was not an MTP device
Dec 25 14:50:20 toshiba upowerd[1299]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.1
Dec 25 14:50:20 toshiba /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD: TOSHIB (/dev/input/event6)
Dec 25 14:50:20 toshiba /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (**) TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD: TOSHIB: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Dec 25 14:50:20 toshiba /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD: TOSHIB'
Dec 25 14:50:20 toshiba upowerd[1299]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0
Dec 25 14:50:20 toshiba upowerd[1299]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3
Dec 25 14:50:21 toshiba /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event6 13:70 fd 59 paused 0
Dec 25 14:50:21 toshiba /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (**) TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD: TOSHIB: always reports core events
Dec 25 14:50:21 toshiba /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event6"
Dec 25 14:50:21 toshiba /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
Dec 25 14:50:21 toshiba /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (II) event6  - TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD: TOSHIB: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Dec 25 14:50:21 toshiba /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (II) event6  - TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD: TOSHIB: device is a keyboard
Dec 25 14:50:21 toshiba /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (II) event6  - TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD: TOSHIB: device removed
Dec 25 14:50:21 toshiba /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/input/input38/event6"
Dec 25 14:50:21 toshiba /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD: TOSHIB" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
Dec 25 14:50:21 toshiba /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
Dec 25 14:50:21 toshiba /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "pt"
Dec 25 14:50:21 toshiba /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
Dec 25 14:50:21 toshiba /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (WW) Option "xkb_options" requires a string value
Dec 25 14:50:21 toshiba /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (II) event6  - TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD: TOSHIB: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Dec 25 14:50:21 toshiba /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (II) event6  - TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD: TOSHIB: device is a keyboard
```

```
$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/14p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 69, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 69, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
```

### Problem

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Watch `sudo journalctl  --follow | tee jc.log` for a few minutes while the camera is misbehaving.

Comment: @waltinator thanks a LOT, indeed the instant the problem occurred, the log outputted much more info. I edited the question accordingly, could you kindly take a look? Thanks again

Comment: @waltinator the problem starts at `Dec 25 14:50:18` with `kernel: usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 15`. Why is USB disconnecting?

Comment: i wonder why your camera is somekind recognized as keyboard?  I mean this parts `TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD: TOSHIB: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard` and `TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD: TOSHIB: device is a keyboard`

Comment: @nobody indeed very strange, do you have idea how to further investigate that?

Comment: @nobody when I do `xinput list` the camera appears there? How can I remove it?

Comment: nope this is normal behaviour.  Please can you paste `sudo  udevadm test --action=add /sys/class/video4linux/video0` and `sudo  udevadm test --action=add /sys/class/video4linux/video1` to https://pastebin.com/